# Unable to install exenstions and updates for Visual Studio 2017 RC (15.0.26014.0)

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I recently installed  Visual Studio 2017 RC (15.0.26014.0) and was trying to install extensions. However while installing any extension using Tools->Extensions and Updates menu fails. Following is installation log.

```
27-Dec-16 10:35:19 AM - Beginning to install extension to Microsoft Visual  Studio Enterprise 2017 RC...
27-Dec-16 10:35:19 AM - Install Error : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.GetCurrentSetupInstance()
at  Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IInstalledExtension& newExtension)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallInternal    (InstallableExtensionImpl extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar,
IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
```

I checked and found corresponding VSIX file is present in temp folder (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp)

Comment: I have the same error, but it raises when extension is to be installed on VS 2012.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently having the same problems.  According to [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/7936/unable-to-install-extensions-after-updating-vs2017.html), repairing the installation might help.